# How do you set crop mode exclusively in Office 2010/2013?

Tags: microsoft-office, images, microsoft-powerpoint, crop, feature-regression

In PowerPoint 2010, when I click an image and choose Crop, I see crop handles and can move them in or out.  However, the resize handles in the same place are also still active, so I sometimes wind up doing a resize operation (which usually distorts the aspect ratio) or I click just away from the handle and wind up moving the picture around within a stationary crop frame, so different parts would be shown.
**Is there any way to disable resize/move during crop operations?**

In PowerPoint 2013, I can't even get crop handles to show or take effect in Crop mode (resize handles only), but that might be a different issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have crop handles only without resize handles. However, you can use the Format Picture pane to get accurate crop. You'll notice from there that Microsoft put Crop and Resize options together too; apparently this was made on purpose so that crop and resize handles share places on pictures.

**Note:** Picture edit tools in Office are still limited to simple use, even after being developed so well. I'd recommend using external image editors for *every* need, regardless of being simple or not.